Introduction of quantum-cryptanalysis tag
Currently quantum-computing is about cryptography performed using quantum computers. Of course, questions that involve Shor's- or Grover's algorithm are not created to perform cryptography. They are used to try to defeat cryptography.
So I thought there needed to be a tag for that. This is also about the technicalities of these algorithms, e.g. discussions about how many qubits are required and so on. After some thought I named this quantum-cryptanalysis. The name is a logical extension of cryptanalysis of course.
I've started a discussion on this topic here to draw attention and to see if everybody agrees on the tag. There is possibly another option: introduce a quantum-computing tag and use it together with cryptanalysis.
 We could also have synonyms, maybe the broader "quantum-algorithms" or more specificly "qubits" but I think quantum-cryptanalysis is a good general term.
Furthermore - if the tag is not shot down - I would like to call in help to provide a better tag description and of course to add the tag to questions that are about quantum cryptanalysis. This would include old questions that are eligible to receive the tag. These may have been incorrectly tagged with quantum-cryptography in the past.
Anywho, this is a discussion, so fire away! And upvote the question if you like the tag and burn it to the ground if you dislike it :)


After some thought I named this quantum-cryptanalysis.

This is a good name and gives us the clear distinction between post-quantum-cryptography, ie classical crypto trying to be resistant to quantum computers, quantum-cryptography, ie cryptographic mechanisms and protocols using quantum computers and quantum-cryptanalysis, ie cryptographic attacks using quantum computers (and quantum oracles?).
Additionally needing two tags to specify one specific intent in combination seems somewhat counter-productive to me and having quantum-computing may lure in people who actually should be on Quantum Computing SE instead.
My suggestion for a tag excerpt would be:

Use this tag on questions about attacks that break cryptographic
  guarantees / security properties of primitives and protocols and
  utilise quantum computers as an essential part.

